# Event Aggregator : How to stop event from propagating further?

Tags: wpf, prism

I am facing an issue where I need to stop propagation of event from event aggregator(Prism Framework).
Is there any way I could do it?

Say I have 10 handlers for an event. Now, i am checking some condition in second event handler and if that condition evaluate to true, i want to stop further processing of the event by rest of 8 event handler.

Comment: Does it work to just add a `.Handled` boolean to the EventArgs, and have all handlers check that flag before processing? I thought that's how I did something similar in the past, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't really the way the observer pattern works. The `EventAggregator` is great for decoupling classes - various things that are interested in a message can `subscribe` to receive it, and anything that wants can `publish` that message out. All without having to know (a) who is sending and (b) who is receiving.

You have no control of the order the message is received, or cancelling it once it has been sent.

You **may** be able to make use of the [Subscription Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) functionality of the EventAggregator, but it isn't something I've had to do before.

Comment: I know by that way I can filter the events. But my problem is that I want to filter the event on the basis of certain condition that is met in one of the event handler.    Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the filtering condition is met in one, and only one, of the subscribers then you should be able to make use of that mechanism - without having to 'cancel' the event handling in the other subscribers.